# Java - Inheritance & Constructors Error

Tags: java, inheritance, types, constructor

I am getting an error when I compile my code due to an issue with my constructors.

**Here is my parent class constructor:**

```
   public BankAccount(final String theNameOfOwner, final double theInterestRate)
   {
      myName = theNameOfOwner;
      myInterestRate = theInterestRate;
      myBalance = 0;
      myMonthlyWithdrawCount = 0;
      myMonthlyServiceCharges = 0;
   }
```

**Here is my child class constructor:**

```
   public SavingsAccount(final String theNameOfOwner, final double theInterestRate)
   {
      BankAccount(theNameOfOwner, theInterestRate);
      myStatusIsActive = false;
      myWithdrawalCounter = 0;
   }
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
SavingsAccount.java:7: error: constructor BankAccount in class BankAccount cannot be applied to given types;
   {
   ^
  required: String,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The error says that I require String,double parameters in my BankAccount call in my child constructor if i'm understanding this correctly.  The only problem is it looks like I have those parameters correct.  Any help/input would be greatly appreciated since I just started programming Java!  Thank you!

Comment: try super instead of parent class name

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 3):

That is not the way to call the superclass constructor.  The compiler thinks you're trying to call a method called `BankAccount` which doesn't exist.  Because there is no explicit call to a superclass constructor, it attempts to insert the implicit call to the default superclass constructor, and that doesn't exist either, leading to the compiler error you see.

Use the `super` keyword to call a superclass constructor.  Change

```
BankAccount(theNameOfOwner, theInterestRate);
```

to

```
super(theNameOfOwner, theInterestRate);
```

Comment: I see!  I never knew that.  I must not have been paying enough attention in class.  Thank you very much sir/madam.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need on the line causing the error is the following instead:

```
super(theNameOfOwner, theInterestRate);
```